# Custom sound not playing when app installed through TestFlight on non-dev device

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have a simple Cordova app that downloads a file called `siren.wav` to `Library/Sounds` at the launch of my app. This sound is supposed to play when a push notification is received. I am using the `phongap-plugin-push` plugin to run GCM to receive push notifications.  However, when the app is in the background, GCM sends notifications through APNs I believe.  I have compiled my app in release mode, uploaded to Apple, and made it available through TestFlight.  I then deleted the debug version of the app from my iPhone and then installed the TestFlight version on my device.  Everything worked perfectly and it played the custom sound whenever I was sent a notification.

Now for the problem: the app was installed on two other iPhones via TestFlight, and the custom sound would not play! Only the default sound played.  To debug, I hooked one of them up to Xcode, and browsed the contents of the sandbox.  Sure enough, `siren.wav`, the custom sound was right in `Library/Sounds`.  I played it in iTunes to make sure that it wasn't corrupted and it played just fine.  So I know the file is there, and in the right place, but it just won't play on other devices when I receive a notification.  Any idea why?

Comment: If you trigger a local notification with the sound, does it work?

Comment: Please post the solution to the problem as an answer, rather than as an edit to the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: Have you Found any Solution... I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: I think I renamed the .wav to a .m4a, but I don't know how it fixed it.  Anyways, I would check if your file is the right type and not corrupted.